# Handling Image upload

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<span class="span3 config_camera_wrapper img-rounded" style="border: 2px solid #fff;" align="center">
<img class="img-rounded" src="images/bookappt_v3/logo-placeholder.png" alt="140x140">
<i class="config_camera img-circle icon-camera icon-2x" onclick="$('#cropImageInput').trigger('click');"></i>.
```

Above is the code for upload image. Check the link to see the how the image upload option looks http://dropmocks.com/mEbKUV.

I tried the below code to upload image.

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='profile_configure_company_details']/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/span[2]/i"));
                upload.sendKeys("/Users/sathiyarengarajan/Desktop/images(1).jpeg");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cropandsave']")).click();
```

But it doesnot works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I work with file uploads during a Webdriver test?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know file uploads always need a `<input type=file>` tag in the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). Your example HTML does not contain any. Often its hidden somewhere in the page, so that input element is not shown on the page. It could also be generated as you the `onclick event` fires. The example page you linked on dropmocks has no upload functionality, it does nothing (or I can't figure out how it should work).

Once you figured out where the `<input>` is located you can use your `sendKeys()` code on that element instead and it should work. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload for more methods to upload a file with Selenium

> I would ask advice of **your development team**, they surely can assist
>   you to find the correct `<input>` tag and help making this test work.

For reference you look at [this example/test styled file uploader](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/styled_file_input.html) or [this question about file uploads without inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350927/file-upload-button-without-input-field).

Comment: **I figured out the code for image upload**.`<span id="cropImageSpan">
<input id="cropImageInput" class="hide" type="file" name="Image">`. **Below is the code I tried**. `driver.findElement(By.id("cropImageInput
")).sendKeys("/Users/sathiyarengarajan/Desktop/bouquet1.jpg");`. **Browse file popup opens and testcase fails**

Comment: Guess the sendKeys is triggering the OS file-dialog. You should try the JavaScript way to inject the filename, see the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300580/webdriver-file-upload